# Alternative PHP Cache and Wordpress Problem

Tags: wordpress, cache, centos

I've installed Alternative PHP Cache with this command:

```
pecl install apc
```

Create and copy to /etc/php.d/
a apc.ini like this:

```
    ; /etc/php.d/apc.ini

extension = apc.so

Directive   Local Value
apc.cache_by_default    On
apc.canonicalize    On
apc.coredump_unmap  Off
apc.enable_cli  Off
apc.enabled On
apc.file_md5    Off
apc.file_update_protection  2
apc.filters no value
apc.gc_ttl  3600
apc.include_once_override   Off
apc.lazy_classes    Off
apc.lazy_functions  Off
apc.max_file_size   1M
apc.mmap_file_mask  /tmp/apc.fmF19e
apc.num_files_hint  2000
apc.preload_path    no value
apc.report_autofilter   Off
apc.rfc1867 Off
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600
apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    120M
apc.slam_defense    Off
apc.stat    On
apc.stat_ctime  Off
apc.ttl 7200
apc.use_request_time    On
apc.user_entries_hint   4096
apc.user_ttl    7200
apc.write_lock  On
```

and then add to php.ini in /etc/
this line: `extension=apc.so`

If I try to load the homepage of the site and some other page that I think that are alredy in cache the system works fine... But when i try to load some other page like home.com/wp-admin I received an error that says the page was not found!
What's wrong?
Thank for the help

P.S. The web site is a wordpress Site and my server OS is Centos

```
Build Date  Jan 7 2011 08:50:02
Configure Command    './configure' '--build=i686-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=i686-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=i386-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/usr/com' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-t1lib=/usr' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-pcre-regex' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--without-mime-magic' '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--with-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--without-mysql' '--without-gd' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC' '--disable-pdo' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter' '--disable-json' '--without-pspell' '--disable-wddx' '--without-curl' '--disable-posix' '--disable-sysvmsg' '--disable-sysvshm' '--disable-sysvsem'
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php.d
additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php.d/apc.ini, /etc/php.d/curl.ini, /etc/php.d/dbase.ini, /etc/php.d/dom.ini, /etc/php.d/gd.ini, /etc/php.d/imap.ini, /etc/php.d/json.ini, /etc/php.d/mbstring.ini, /etc/php.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php.d/sqlite2.ini, /etc/php.d/wddx.ini, /etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini, /etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php.d/xsl.ini, /etc/php.d/zip.ini
PHP API 20041225
PHP Extension   20060613
Zend Extension  220060519
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   disabled
Zend Memory Manager enabled
IPv6 Support    enabled
Registered PHP Streams  https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, data, http, ftp, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
Registered Stream Filters   zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed


Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_call_time_pass_reference  Off Off
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
always_populate_raw_post_data   Off Off
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
asp_tags    Off Off
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    no value    no value
default_charset no value    no value
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
define_syslog_variables Off Off
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   no value    no value
display_errors  Off Off
display_startup_errors  Off Off
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   On  On
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   no value    no value
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting 6143    6143
expose_php  On  On
extension_dir   /usr/lib/php/modules    /usr/lib/php/modules
file_uploads    On  On
highlight.bg    #FFFFFF #FFFFFF
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    .:  .:
log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
magic_quotes_gpc    Off Off
magic_quotes_runtime    Off Off
magic_quotes_sybase Off Off
mail.add_x_header   Off Off
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
max_execution_time  30  30
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
memory_limit    64M 64M
open_basedir    /var/www/vhosts/
output_buffering    4096    4096
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   8M  8M
precision   14  14
realpath_cache_size 16K 16K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  Off Off
register_globals    Off Off
register_long_arrays    Off Off
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
safe_mode   Off Off
safe_mode_exec_dir  no value    no value
safe_mode_gid   Off Off
safe_mode_include_dir   no value    no value
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
serialize_precision 100 100
short_open_tag  On  On
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sql.safe_mode   Off Off
track_errors    Off Off
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M
upload_tmp_dir  no value    no value
user_dir    no value    no value
variables_order EGPCS   EGPCS
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
y2k_compliance  On  On
zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off Off


apache2handler

Apache Version  Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Apache API Version  20051115

User/Group  apache(48)/48
Max Requests    Per Child: 3000 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 400
Timeouts    Connection: 15 - Keep-Alive: 5
Virtual Server  Yes
Server Root /etc/httpd
Loaded Modules  core prefork http_core mod_so mod_auth_basic mod_auth_digest mod_authn_file mod_authn_alias mod_authn_anon mod_authn_dbm mod_authn_default mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_authz_owner mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_dbm mod_authz_default util_ldap mod_authnz_ldap mod_include mod_log_config mod_logio mod_env mod_ext_filter mod_mime_magic mod_expires mod_deflate mod_headers mod_usertrack mod_setenvif mod_mime mod_dav mod_status mod_autoindex mod_info mod_dav_fs mod_vhost_alias mod_negotiation mod_dir mod_actions mod_speling mod_userdir mod_alias mod_rewrite mod_proxy mod_proxy_balancer mod_proxy_ftp mod_proxy_http mod_proxy_connect mod_cache mod_suexec mod_disk_cache mod_file_cache mod_mem_cache mod_cgi mod_version mod_bw mod_fcgid mod_jk mod_perl mod_php5 mod_proxy_ajp mod_python mod_ssl



apc

APC Support enabled
Version 3.1.8
APC Debugging   Disabled
MMAP Support    Enabled
MMAP File Mask  /tmp/apc.Zcgcs7
Locking type    pthread mutex Locks
Serialization Support   php
Revision    $Revision: 308812 $
Build Date  May 12 2011 19:38:59

Directive   Local Value Master Value
apc.cache_by_default    On  On
apc.canonicalize    On  On
apc.coredump_unmap  Off Off
apc.enable_cli  Off Off
apc.enabled On  On
apc.file_md5    Off Off
apc.file_update_protection  2   2
apc.filters no value    no value
apc.gc_ttl  0   0
apc.include_once_override   Off Off
apc.lazy_classes    Off Off
apc.lazy_functions  Off Off
apc.max_file_size   10M 10M
apc.mmap_file_mask  /tmp/apc.Zcgcs7 /tmp/apc.Zcgcs7
apc.num_files_hint  4096    4096
apc.preload_path    no value    no value
apc.report_autofilter   Off Off
apc.rfc1867 Off Off
apc.rfc1867_freq    0   0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_ upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600    3600
apc.serializer  default default
apc.shm_segments    1   1
apc.shm_size    32  32
apc.slam_defense    Off Off
apc.stat    On  On
apc.stat_ctime  Off Off
apc.ttl 7200    7200
apc.use_request_time    On  On
apc.user_entries_hint   4096    4096
apc.user_ttl    7200    7200
apc.write_lock  On  On

bz2

BZip2 Support   Enabled
Stream Wrapper support  compress.bz2://
Stream Filter support   bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version   1.0.3, 15-Feb-2005

calendar

Calendar support    enabled

ctype

ctype functions enabled

curl

cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5

date

date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    Europe/Berlin

Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   no value    no value

dom

DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version  2.6.26
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support enabled

exif

EXIF Support    enabled
EXIF Version    1.4 $Id: exif.c 293036 2010-01-03 09:23:27Z sebastian $
Supported EXIF Version  0220
Supported filetypes JPEG,TIFF

filter

Input Validation and Filtering  enabled
Revision    $Revision: 298196 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
filter.default  unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags    no value    no value

ftp

FTP support enabled

gd

GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.2.1
T1Lib Support   enabled
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPG Support enabled
PNG Support enabled
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support enabled
XBM Support enabled

gettext

GetText Support enabled

gmp

gmp support enabled
GMP version 4.1.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a conflict with zend optimizer.

You can disable zend by commenting out this line in your php.ini file:

`zend_extension ="path/to/extension_dir/zend_optimizer.so"`

#### Update:

php.ini settings look fine.

There is a [bug report regarding file includes](http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=22687) APC 3.1.8 that causes a fatal php error:  `failed to open stream: No such file or
directory`

I would try removing APC and recompile version 3.1.7 and see if your errors go away.

Comment: thanks for the answers. I tried to comment this line but apc doesn't work, any othes suggestions?

Comment: Did you restart Apache?  Zend and APC will not work together it's either one or the other.  Can you run a phpinfo(); and post the results (remove any sensitive data)?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: How can i send you the result? can you share with me your mail?

Comment: See answer edit.  All settings look fine.